# Deploy a single service in Rancher stack

Tags: rancher

I'm changing the deployment process, currently we have multiple services in a single stack and every time we deploy all the services. Going forward we need to deploy a single service not whole stack on Rancher.
Is it possible?
if yes, kindly guide me to the link. I tried google but couldn't find any relevant info.

Comment: Can you not create one stack per service?

Comment: We already created single stack multiple services.

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is, can you please elaborate? Are you trying to find out how to upgrade a service in a multi service stack?